# Multiprocessing.pool error : raise self._value sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

What could be the cause of this error?

```
File "/pga/mcad/install/python/python-2.7.6.9/linux/RH6/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/pga/mcad/install/python/python-2.7.6.9/linux/RH6/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be having a parenthesis in your regular expression without the escape character `\` preceding it.

> You need to escape the parenthesis using '\' since they are a reserved
>   character in regular expressions, used for retrieving the values
>   inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If yes, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer